# Web application to run identical analysis on different datasets (questionnaires)

Tags: data-analysis, survey, analytics, business-intelligence

I am part of a small team developing a web application to be used by banks to analyze loan applications of small and medium farmers. The value of this software for banks is in embedded agronomic know-how. However I also have to develop and maintain the platform that supports the business logic and data, which is a problem for me. My goal is to focus on the agronomic database and the algorithm and use a third-party solution that would take care of the rest. A paid solution is OK.

Typical workflow of our application looks like this:

- A bank staff (e.g. a loan officer) logs in to the web site
- Each bank has its own workspace on the site with data separated from other banks'. Agronomic know-how and business logic is the same for all of them though. So this loan officer finds herself in her bank's workspace on the web site.
- She clicks "new client" and fills in farmer application (questionnaire).
- Alternatively, she can open one of the farmer questionnaires stored in the bank's workspace and review/edit/add information.
- When work on the questionnaire is complete she can click "Analyze" and get results of applying our system's business logic to that questionnaire. The results are in the form of various reports either in tables or charts that the loan officer can review.
- A Word/Excel report can also be generated.

It seems to me that this kind of workflow must be so widespread that platforms supporting it must exist. However I am unable to find it. I guess it must be something like business intelligence suite, but not centered on doing all kinds of analysis on the same data, but rather doing the same analysis on different data sets (farmer applications).

Basically, I need a system to enter and store data, process data, and output data that would be customizable at every step related to that (the questionnaire, the data transformations, and the resulting tables and charts), but providing a charting library, a Word/Excel export library, access rights management, and basic web application support stuff.